# Use Func in Linq to Entity as generic method parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to create function based on Entity Framework which will update Table in SQL database.

This table have parent-child relationship, so I am updating the bunch of children based on `parentID`.

I want to have a generic function and I don't know how to get the ID out of the object whose definition is not known at compilation time.

I tried to use `Func` which could be pretty neat, but it can't be used in Linq-To-Entities.

Code:

```
protected static void update<TEntity>(DbSet<TEntity> set, int parentID,
  List<TEntity> entities, Func<TEntity, bool> isNew, Func<TEntity, int> getID = null, 
  Func<TEntity, int> getParentID, Action<TEntity, TEntity> updateSingleEntity)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var currentIDs = entities.Select(e => getID(e));

        var newEntities = entities.Where(e => isNew(e));
        var existingEntities = entities.Where(e => !isNew(e));

        var deletedEntities 
          = set.Where(e => getParentID(e) == parentID && !currentIDs.Contains(getID(e)));

        foreach (var toAdd in newEntities)
        {
            set.Add(toAdd);
        }

        foreach (var toDelete in deletedEntities)
        {
            var entity = set.Find(getID(toDelete));
            set.Remove(entity);
        }

        foreach (var toUpdate in existingEntities)
        {
            var entity = set.Find(getID(toUpdate));
            updateSingleEntity(toUpdate, entity);
        }
    }
```

I'd like to use this function like this:

```
   update(set, parentID, someList, e => e.ID != 0, e => e.ID, e => ParentID, somefunc);
```

It's pretty neat IMO. Is there any way to implement a function like this?

I cannot do ( I tried):

Interface which has ID property can be neat. But I am not able to define `parentID` then in this interface because the name of this property varies around entities in DB.

Comment: Func will not work. Use Expression<Func ... instead

Comment: I tried to use but when i use it then i have this error :
'getID' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'.
Declaration :     Expression<Func<TEntity, int>> getID.
Usage : getID(toDelete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as you've been told in the comment, you need to use `Expression<Func<TEntity,int>> getId`.

To use it, don't do this `entities.Select(e => getID(e))` but simply this `entities.Select(getID)`. The reason is that `Select` expects a lamba expression, and `getId` contains the lambda expression. The `Expression<>` is necessary so it's an expression tree necessary for EF to work, and not a compiled expression. You can read [this for more information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710(v=vs.110).aspx).

As to the alternative solution of an interface, you would have to implement it like this:

```
public interface IId
{
   public int GetId();
}
```

Then, you need to implement it in all your classes, for example like this:

```
public int GetId() { return parentId; }
```

or

```
public int GetId() { return parentId; }
```

You should also have to add the interface constraint to the generic method like this: `where TEntity: class ,IId`

However you'd find two problems:

1. You would need to implement the `GetId` for all your entity types (or at least for those which will be used with thid method)
2. The `GetId` function could not be translated to an expression tree, so EF wouldn't know how to convert it into a SQL expression. (I'm not sure, but it would even perhaps raise an error).

Answer (score 1):

I think your function should look like this:

```
protected static void Update<TEntity>(DbSet<TEntity> set, Expression<Func<TEntity, int>> getParentID, int parentID, List<TEntity> entities, Func<TEntity, int> getID, Action<TEntity, TEntity> updateSingleEntity)
    where TEntity : class
{
    var filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(Expression.Equal(getParentID.Body, Expression.Constant(parentID)), getParentID.Parameters[0]);
    var targetEntities = set.Where(filter).ToDictionary(getID);
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        var entityID = getID(entity);
        TEntity targetEntity;
        if (!targetEntities.TryGetValue(entityID, out targetEntity))
            set.Add(entity);
        else
        {
            updateSingleEntity(targetEntity, entity);
            targetEntities.Remove(entityID);
        }
    }
    if (targetEntities.Count > 0)
        set.RemoveRange(targetEntities.Values);
}
```

and use it like this:

```
update(set, e => e.ParentID, parentID, someList, e => e.ID, somefunc);
```